# infinite loop stackoverflow list of objects exception

Tags: c#, list, csv, while-loop

i have this code:

```
public List<CsvUserData> CsvUserList = new List<CsvUserData>();

public CsvUserData()
{
    readCSV(@"C:\userdata.csv");
}

public string CSVEmailEditText { get; set; }
public string CSVNameEditText { get; set; }
public string CSVAddressEditText { get; set; }
public string CSVPostnumEditText { get; set; }
public string CSVCityEditText { get; set; }
public string CSVPhoneEditText { get; set; }
public string CSVCommentEditText { get; set; }
public string SelectPage { get; set; }

private void readCSV(string location)
{
    var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(location));
    string line;
    string[] values;
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        line = reader.ReadLine();
        values = line.Split(',');

        CsvUserList.Add
        (
            new CsvUserData
            {
                CSVEmailEditText = values[0],
                CSVNameEditText = values[1],
                CSVAddressEditText = values[2],
                CSVPostnumEditText = values[3],
                CSVCityEditText = values[4],
                CSVPhoneEditText = values[5],
            }
        );
    }
}
```

I am trying to read `csv` file into list that consists of objects named `CsvUserData`, the class definition is displayed above. Once the class is instantiated my program is getting into infinite loop eventually resulting in `stackoverflow` exception once the list memory is full, even though my csv file only has one row of data. Can someone help me and explain why is this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let’s see:

1. Create a new `CsvUserData` object, call the constructor.
2. `readCSV(@"C:\userdata.csv");`
3. Inside `readCSV`: Open file, and iterate over the lines.
4. For each line: `new CsvUserData { … }`
5. Go to 1.

So you end up creating new `CsvUserData` objects from *within* the constructor of the `CsvUserData` type. So this will repeat forever.

You probably meant to make the `readCSV` method static or something, and only call it *once*. There is really no reason why it should be called from the constructor. And the constructor shouldn’t really open a file and create stuff based on the file; that’s far too much work for a constructor.

Comment: Thank you very much, I guess i created a recursive constructor, I was focusing on my while loop and didn't see that. That solved my problem I will accept the answer in 5 minutes :)